# Key Value Pair Search using Marklogic Java API

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-8, marklogic-9

I have One XML Stored in Marklogic as Mentioned Below

```
<employee>
    <name>Shiv</name>
    <address>.....</address>
    <phone>......</phone>
    <email>...</email>
</employee>
```

So my requirement is, I want to search `<name>` tag and its value as `Shiv` using marklogic java api.

I tried using `KeyValueQueryDefinition` and it is working fine but `KeyValueQueryDefinition`   is now deprecated so i can't go with this.

```
QueryManager queryMgr = client.newQueryManager();
KeyValueQueryDefinition query = queryMgr.newKeyValueDefinition();
query.put(queryMgr.newElementLocator(new QName("name")), "Shiv");
SearchHandle resultsHandle = new SearchHandle();
queryMgr.search(query, resultsHandle);
```

So I need alternative to `KeyValueQueryDefinition` which satisfy my above requirement and also i don't want to create Element Range Index for `<name>` tag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A value query is equivalent to a KeyValueQueryDefinition.  Something along the following lines should work:

```
QueryManager queryMgr = client.newQueryManager();
StructuredQueryBuilder qryBldr = new StructuredQueryBuilder();
StructuredQueryDefinition query = qryBldr.value(qryBldr.element("name"), "Shiv");
SearchHandle resultsHandle = new SearchHandle();
queryMgr.search(query, resultsHandle);
```

See:

http://docs.marklogic.com/javadoc/client/com/marklogic/client/query/StructuredQueryBuilder.html#value-com.marklogic.client.query.StructuredQueryBuilder.TextIndex-java.lang.String...-

Hoping that helps,

Comment: It is Working Perfectly...Thank you @ehennum